# dynamical set variable

Tags: php, class

I have trouble with dynamical variable in class;

```
<?
  class test {
    public static function set($key, $value) {
      self::$$key = $value; 
    }
  }
  test::set('testKey', 'testValue');
?>
```

How can I set variables, which would then access a test::$testKey ?

Some time later:

```
<?
  class test {
    public static $dynamic;
    public static function set($key, $value) {
      self::$dynamic->$key = $value;
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $agrs) {
      echo self::$dynamic->$method;
    }
  }
  test::$dynamic = new test();
  test::set("hey", "test");
  test::hey();
?>
```

how about this solution?

Comment: with 1 '$' - Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: test::$key. with 2 '$' - Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: test::$testKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to create dynamical static  variables in php.